# page reload after JS function executes

Tags: javascript, php

I am loading a table dynamically from DB in php. One column in the table are check boxes. On the column header onclick I remove checked entries from the DB. At the end of the function I call location.reload() in hope to refresh the table but it won't happen. If I manually hit F5 it works as expected. How should I upload the table please?

Comment: Use Ajax instead. `location.reload()` is just reloading from the browser cache, not hitting the server again.

Comment: Do you have code examples? This sounds like a job for ajax.

Comment: location.reload(true) does not work. how do I use the ajax? I am a beginner in web developing. Thanks for minus points for my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function function_name() {
    $.ajax({
        url     : "/php/data/get_table_data.php",
        type    : "get",
        data    : {
            "arg1" : "some_arg",
            "arg2" : "another_arg"
        },
        success : function(data) {
            /* Fill table with contents of "data" */
        },
        error   : function() {
            /* Something goes wrong… */
        }
    });
};
```

This is a small example on how to use Ajax with the jQuery library.

When you use Ajax then you don't even need to refresh the whole page but the data in the table will get fetched and updated in the background.
**Which means**; no lagging UI, no page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

According to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload

you should pass `true` as an argument to location.reload() to suppress caching.

Comment: Could you post your onclick handler?  I suspect that what's happening is that the reload is being requested before your entry deletion code on the server has completed running.